# Post-mortem debugging in vscode-python?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

Python's post-mortem debugging (easily accessible by IPython's `%debug` magic) allows to step out of the exception's scope one or more times and view the variables as they were before the exception was thrown. Extremely useful.

VSCode-python has nice integration with Python's debugger. If a breakpoint is introduced, one can step in and out of functions in the editor using the debug toolbar. This is much more user friendly than using the console for debugging. However, this debug toolbar doesn't seem to work in a post mortem mode.

When a Python script is run in vscode using the "Start debugging" command (F5) and throws an exception, the exception is highlighted in vscode's editor, but stepping out doesn't work - the script immediately quits if I click step out in the debug toolbar.

Is there a way to integrate Python's post-mortem debugging with vscode's editor? Am I missing something? I was expecting this to just work.

Answer (score 1):

The `step out` button might not work, but that doesn't mean you can't look up previous frames, probe their variables, and even run expressions in those frames.

All you have to do is select the frames (functions) you're interested in, in the `Call Stack` subdivision of the `Run and Debug` sidebar:

[image: Call Stack subdivision of the Run and Debug sidebar]

After clicking on one of those frames, you can see the frame variables in the `Variables` subdivision, and even run expressions using them in the `Debug Console`.

This is essentially the same functionality of the `up` and `down` commands from (i)pdb that are available in the `%debug` magic of IPython.

Comment: You should also check the "Uncaught Exceptions" and "User Uncaught Exceptions" in the Breakpoint window to get the VSCode debugger into a post mortem mode

Comment: The question was about postmortem debugging, but this answer seems to be about live debugging. Can you do what you suggest postmortem?

Comment: @moos, as can be seen from the screenshot, the stack in the debugger is in handling a `ZeroDivisionError` exception, so yes, this can be done "postmortem" in the same sense of the `pdb.post_mortem()` [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.post_mortem) in Python (which is what is used by the `%debug` magic in IPython as mentioned by the OP). That is: the code is still running, and the exception, with its stack trace, is being examined by the debugger.